# Polynomial Factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(2^x)+(2^{-x})=a$.  What is $(8^x)+(8^{-x})$?

I did:
$$\begin{align} (2^x)^3+(2^{-x})^3
 &= [(2^x)+(2^{-x})] [(2^x)^2-(2^x)(2^{-x})+(2^{-x})^2]
\\&= a [(2^x)^2+2(2^x)(2^{-x})+(2^{-x})^2-3(2^x)(2^{-x})]
\\&= a {[(2^x)+(2^{-x})]^2-3(2^x)(2^{-x})}
\\&= a [a^2-3(2^x)(2^{-x})]
\\&= a^3-3a(2^x)(2^{-x}) \end{align}$$
The answer is $(a^3-3a)$. But I don't know how to solve now. Please, could you help me?

Comment: Post edit, it looks done.  $2^x\times 2^{-x}=1$ so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solution looks good. One typo: on line 3, it should read $...-3a(2^x)(2^{-x})$ instead of $...-3(2^x)(2^{-x})$. You're so close! Note that $(2^x)(2^{-x})=1$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks Dave!!! Now that I noticed that this expression is equals to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The posted proof looks good. Alternatively, using the identity $(u+v)^3=u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)$:

$$a^3=(2^x+2^{-x})^3=\left(2^x\right)^3+\left(2^{-x}\right)^3+3\cdot 2^x\cdot 2^{-x}(2^x + 2^{-x})=8^x+8^{-x}+ 3 \cdot 1 \cdot a$$